# Reference at std::thread parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading, pass-by-reference, stdthread, pass-by-const-reference

I have two functions

```
void f(const int &x) {}
void g(int& x) {}
```

I can make

```
int x = 0;
std::thread t1(f, x);
```

But I can't create `std::thread t2(g, x)`, in this case i need make `std::ref(x)` instead of just `x`, why is it necessary?

And why it possible to create `t1` without `std::cref`?

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: `std::thread` copies the arguments to the function. `std::ref` wraps your object in a `std::reference_wrapper` which grants reference semantics, so copies refer to the original object.

Comment: okay, I got it. But why `t1` is successfully created without `std::cref`?

Comment: The type information of all the involved parameters is important in C++. Please write out a compilable example that shows the issue. From this `std::thread t1(f, x)` it is impossible to tell because we don't know what `f` or `x` are!

Comment: Full code https://ideone.com/KjOIKc. And it works also is case when I change `int` to any type. Why is it compile and does not requere pass `x` by `std::cref`?

Comment: @АртёмГаркавый If you don't use `std::ref` the original argument will just be copied to a different `int`. And an `int` is a perfectly valid object to bind to `const int &` so there is no error, except that you don't get the pass-by-reference behavior you expected. But the compiler is fine with that.

Comment: Wow, it really copies. I try an example (https://ideone.com/5H80EI), and this cycle run infinitely, it really copies passes values, is it C++ bug?

Comment: @АртёмГаркавый Please include full code as a part of the question, **and** make sure the code is minimal. When asked to clarify, please *fix the question*, don't just add information in the comments. The question should be complete **with all comments removed**. In fact, comments are sometimes removed wholesale when they seem to be too chatty. So use comments as input to improve the question, but don't "leak" question into the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `f()` function does not work as you expect without `std::cref()`.

Although `f()` does not intent to change the value behind `x`, it does not mean that the value behind this reference cannot be mutated elsewhere.

In this example, without `std::cref()` a copy of the original `int` is put in the thread stack, and `x` references this copy; we see `1` and `1`.

On the other hand, with `std::cref()`, `x` still references the original; we see `1` and `2`.

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined -pthread
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
void
f(const int &x)
{
  std::cout << "x=" << x << '\n';
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
  std::cout << "x=" << x << '\n';
}

int
main()
{
  int i=1;
  // std::thread th{f, i}; // copy to thread stack
  std::thread th{f, std::cref(i)}; // reference the original i
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  i+=1;
  th.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a pity that C++ by stealth will copy objects. BTW, why this code worked when I change std::cref to std::ref? Should the behavior be the same?

Comment: @АртёмГаркавый `x` is a reference on `const` thus providing a mutable reference wrapper does not harm. On the other hand, providing a const-reference wrapper where a reference on a mutable object is expected (`g()` in your question) would make the compiler complain.

Comment: @АртёмГаркавый *It's a pity that C++ by stealth will copy objects* There's a fine line between "stealth" and "not understanding enough about the fundamental semantics of C++". Those semantics aren't self-obvious, although they did arise in the design process of the language, and usually are a particular way because otherwise something "simple" would break or become even less obvious. That's what it means to become experienced with C++: such understanding is inherent to effective use of the language. A lot of stuff appears stealthy to a relative novice, no matter the programming language.